# Loading differents divs on click action on map using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, dictionary

I have a div sequence in the page:

```
http://foo.com/pagewithdiv
```

as following:

```
<div id="list1" class="alist" style="display:none;">content1</div>
 <div id="list2" class="alist" style="display:none;">content2</div>
 <div id="list3" class="alist" style="display:none;">content3</div>
 <div id="list4" class="alist" style="display:none;">content4</div>
 <div id="list5" class="alist" style="display:none;">content5</div>
 <div id="list6" class="alist" style="display:none;">content6</div>
 <div id="list7" class="alist" style="display:none;">content7</div>
 <div id="list8" class="alist" style="display:none;">content8</div>
 <div id="list9" class="alist" style="display:none;">content9</div>
 <div id="list10" class="alist" style="display:none;">content10</div>
```

In the other page:

```
http://foo.com/test
```

i have a map as following:

```
(area1)    <area shape="circle" coords="309,187,20" href="#" onclick="">
(area2)    <area shape="circle" coords="310,123,20" href="#" onclick="">
(area3)    <area shape="circle" coords="260,187,20" href="#" onclick="">
(area4)    <area shape="circle" coords="260,123,20" href="#" onclick="">
(area5)    <area shape="circle" coords="210,187,20" href="#" onclick="">
(area6)    <area shape="circle" coords="210,123,20" href="#" onclick="">
(area7)    <area shape="circle" coords="160,187,20" href="#" onclick="">
(area8)    <area shape="circle" coords="159,123,20" href="#" onclick="">
(area9)    <area shape="circle" coords="111,187,20" href="#" onclick="">
(area10)   <area shape="circle" coords="111,123,20" href="#" onclick="">
```

when i click on area shape (area1) I would load in same  test page the div "list1" content and display it under the map 
when i click on area shape (area2) I would load in same  test page the div "list2" (replacing list1) content and display it under the map 
I don't want use show hide function by loading all divs in same page test because the page would become heavy.

I would like use a ajax function so as

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://foo.com/pagewithdiv
",
    dataType: "json"
}).success(function(data){
    $('#data').append(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

but I do not know how to do it
Could you help me?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want will require a different solution than you are proposing.

First, you'll want the Ajax call to hit a URL that returns a dynamic response based on a URL parameter. Then some HTML and JavaScript:

```
<map onclick="return loadDiv(event)">
    <area shape="circle" coords="309,187,20" href="http://foo.com/pagewithdiv?id=list1">
    <area shape="circle" coords="310,123,20" href="http://foo.com/pagewithdiv?id=list2">
    <area shape="circle" coords="260,187,20" href="http://foo.com/pagewithdiv?id=list3">
    <area shape="circle" coords="260,123,20" href="http://foo.com/pagewithdiv?id=list4">
    <area shape="circle" coords="210,187,20" href="http://foo.com/pagewithdiv?id=list5">
    <area shape="circle" coords="210,123,20" href="http://foo.com/pagewithdiv?id=list6">
    <area shape="circle" coords="160,187,20" href="http://foo.com/pagewithdiv?id=list7">
    <area shape="circle" coords="159,123,20" href="http://foo.com/pagewithdiv?id=list8">
    <area shape="circle" coords="111,187,20" href="http://foo.com/pagewithdiv?id=list9">
    <area shape="circle" coords="111,123,20" href="http://foo.com/pagewithdiv?id=list10">
</map>

<div id="data"></div>

<script>
    function loadDiv(event) {
        // Make event cross browser
        event = event || window.event;
        event.target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        event.preventDefault = event.preventDefault || function() {
            this.returnValue = false;
        };

        var url = event.target.href;

        if (!url) {
            return true;
        }

        event.preventDefault();

        console.log("Make Ajax request to " + url);

        // Make sure <AREA> href values are in the same domain as the page running this JavaScript.
        // AJAX currently fails in JSFiddle due to the same domain policy in browsers.
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: "html",
            method: "GET"
        }).success(function(data) {
            $("#data").html(data);
        })
        .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
            $("#data").html("Ajax request failed to " + url +
                            "<br>Status: " + xhr.status + " (" + status + "), Error: " + error);
        });
    }
</script>
```

The AJAX call to /pagewithdiv?id=N should return the snippet of HTML you want to put in the DIV#data element.

Edit: Since the AJAX URL is taken from the `href` of the AREA tag, you can use static files on the server too. Just put the contents for each AREA in its own TXT or HTML file:

```
<area ... href="/pages/a.html">
<area ... href="/pages/b.html">
```

It's really up to you and pretty flexible.

I just changed the `loadDiv` code to make it even more flexible. As long as the element that got clicked as an `href` attribute, it should work.

Edit: Fixed a syntax error

Comment: I have tried your code but i have modified .success: because give me a error with: 

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://foo.com/pagewithdiv",
            dataType: "html"
        }).success(function(data) {
            $("#data").html(data);
        });
    }
 it work but when i click the area map it brings me to page: pagewithdiv instead i want remain on page: test

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot to add `return false` to cancel the click event. Don't forget to use `return loadDiv(event)` in the MAP onclick handler.

Comment: it continue to bring me to page: pagewithdiv  can you create a working demo with jsfiddle for me? thanks

Comment: Just change the `href` attributes on the AREA tags so it points to the URL that should contain the content for that link.

Comment: I'm tryng the problem is that i'm working in a wordpress site and don't have pages with .html extension

Comment: You don't need pages with a .html extension. Any URL that returns HTML will work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46497/discussion-between-grigione-and-greg-burghardt)

Answer (score 1):

See the **Loading Page Fragments** section of jQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
$("area#area1").on("click", function() {
  $("div#data").load("/pagewithdiv #list1");
});
```